# plotting bar chart colour x & y axis and change font size

Tags: matlab

I have a bar chart. I need to format the appearance of the chart. I have managed to change the font size but can't change the font colour? I can also not change the colour of the edge of the chart - the box around the whole chart?

Below is my code. Have tried various options but am a bit lost.

```
x_labels(:, 1) = name_splitter(data_cell(2:end, 1)')';
h=figure;
np = bar(chart_data);

ax = get(gca);
cat = ax.Children;
set(gca,'XtickL',x_labels)

set(gca,'FontSize',8);
title('Tracking Errors', 'FontSize',10,'Color',My_Blue(1, :),'FontWeight','Bold');        

scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
set(h,'Position',[1 scrsz(4)/2 scrsz(3)/2.3 scrsz(4)/7.0],'Resize','off')
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')

set(cat(1),'FaceColor', My_Blue(1, :));

saveas(h,[pathfig 'my_chart.eps'],'epsc');

close(h);
```

[image: my plot] So I would like the font to be blue for the x & y axis. I also would like the outside box (where the red arrow is pointing to) to be blue as well.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your figure and point out what doesn't work? Without access to your data, it's impossible to replicate the issue. The title command with the font colour should work.

Comment: just added the image, hope that helps

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is really about changing the colour of the box, the title seems to be OK based on your screenshot. Have you tried `set(gca,'Box','on','XColor','b','YColor','b')`?

Comment: yes that works perfectly thank-you. If you want to post your reply as an answer happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your question is really about changing the colour of the box, the title seems to be OK based on your screenshot. Have you tried?

```
set(gca,'Box','on','XColor','b','YColor','b')
```

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html):

> **Box** — Axes box outline
>
> `'off' (default) | 'on'`
>
> Axes box outline, specified as one of these values:
>
> `'off'` — Do not display the box outline around the axes.
>
> `'on'` — Display the box outline around the axes. In a 3-D view, the
>   outline appears around the axes back planes. Use the BoxStyle property
>   to change the extent of the outline.
>
> The `XColor`, `YColor`, and `ZColor` properties control the color of the
>   outline.